# exercise equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could anyone please check my task on equivalence relation? THank you!! I gues the form is not very correct, Has anyone a better idea?

In this task it says: if $f:X\to Y$ is a transformation. We define the relation $R$ to $X$:

$$x'∼_R x''\iff f(x')=f(x'')$$

Show if it´s equivalence relation.

reflexive: yes $x'\sim_R x'' \iff f(x') =f(x'')$; $1\sim 2 \iff 4 =4$

symmetrical, no

$x'\sim_R x''\iff  f(x') = f(x'')$ it´s not clearly defined to which $x$ the image belongs

transitive, yes $x'\sim_R x'' \iff f(x') = f(x'')$; $1\sim 2 \iff 4 = 4$; $x''\sim_R x'''\iff f(x'') = f(x''')$; $2\sim 3 \iff 4 =4$ then $x'\sim_R x'''\iff =f(x') = f(x''')$; $1\sim 3 \iff 4 =4$

Comment: Sophia, in some places I had to guess what you intended; please check to see whether I interpreted everything correctly.

Comment: @Sophia:i think your proof is true but i don't know whats $1\sim 2 \iff 4 =4$

Comment: well I tried to say, if x´=1 and x´´=2 both have the same image, which is 4. is this okay?

Comment: at Brian scott: yes thank you, it´s right interpreted.thank you so much for he effort! so this is right solution for the task now

Comment: Not really, no, because you don’t know what the function $f$ is. In fact $\sim_R$ **is** an equivalence, relation, no matter what $f$ is.

Comment: I think you need to include how $f(x)$ is defined, and what domain if the values you are referring to reflect some elements in a domain, and $f(x)$ the image of those elements.

Comment: but the task doesnt say how f(x) is defined. so I thought I can just take random numbers??

Comment: sorry I think i don´t get how to solve this at all. could one of you please suppose a way of solving it?? sorry i need so much help.

Comment: No, you have to do it without knowing what $f$ is. And you don’t need to know. For symmetry, for instance, if $x\sim_R x'$, then $f(x)=f(x')$, so $f(x')=f(x)$, and therefore $x'\sim_R x$.

Comment: I’ll write up an answer.

Comment: See Brian's comment: you don't need to know f(x). And you don't need to assign arbitrary numbers, because you don't know what the image of those numbers are.  Use generic variables $x_1, x_2, x_3$

Comment: thank you brian scott!! so would reflexive be: x~ Rx, then f(x)=f(x)

Comment: and transitive: x~x´, then f(x)=f(x´)     x´~x´´, then f(x´)=f(x´´), so x~x´´, then f(x)=f(x´´)

Comment: That’s almost right for transitivity, but you said the last step backwards. From $x\sim_R x'$ and $x'\sim_R x''$ you have $f(x)=f(x')$ and $f(x')=f(x'')$; those give you $f(x)=f(x'')$, and **then** you deduce that $x\sim_R x''$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re right that you have to show that $\sim_R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

- Reflexive: You have to show that for every $x\in X$, $x\sim_R x$. Okay, what does $x\sim_R x$ mean? By definition it means that $f(x)=f(x)$. That’s certainly true for every $x\in X$, so $\sim_R$ is reflexive.
- Symmetric: You have to show that for every $x,x'\in X$, if $x\sim_R x'$, then $x'\sim_R x$. Again, what does it mean to say that $x\sim_R x'$? It means that $f(x)=f(x')$. But if that’s true, then it’s certainly also true that $f(x')=f(x)$, and that, by definition, means that $x'\sim_R x$. Thus, $\sim_R$ is symmetric.
- Transitive: You have to show that for every $x,x',x''\in X$, if $x\sim_R x'$ and $x'\sim_R x''$, then $x\sim_R x''$. Here again you should start by asking what it means to have $x\sim_R x'$ and $x'\sim_R x''$. By the definition of $\sim_R$ it means that $f(x)=f(x')$ and $f(x')=f(x'')$. But equality is transitive, so this means that $f(x)=f(x'')$, which is exactly what we wanted: that’s the definition of $x\sim_R x''$. Thus, $\sim_R$ is transitive.

Since $\sim_R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, it’s an equivalence relation on $X$.

I don’t know whether you’ve yet learned about equivalence classes, but if not, you will soon: the equivalence class of an element $x\in X$ is the set of all $x'\in X$ such that $x\sim_R x'$. For this relation that’s precisely $\{x'\in X:f(x)=f(x')\}$, the set of all points of $X$ that get sent by $f$ to the place as $x$.

Comment: thank you so very much for your help!!

Comment: @Sophia: You’re very welcome.